# How to create soap client in eclipse with x509 certificate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, x509certificate, soap-client, ws-security

I want to create a Soap Client from local WSDL. 
So I have create new J2EE project, then I have import WSDL file, right click ok it, web services, generate Client.

Now the server require SSL certificate to call it, so I have download this certificate and I have add it on my keystore. 
Now if I try to run client I can connect at server soap but I have an error. The error is

> Exception: ERROR: No security header found in the message Message: ERROR: No security header found in the message

If I read the WSDL, there are 5 attribute that I MUST signing by X509 Certificate. I have this file on my local PC. The file name is

> "keystore_healthnetbr.jks"

Now, I can generate a client with signing these attribute?

regards

Comment: Are you connecting to a WCF service? Are you building a standalone client or are you using a framework?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a security interceptor to your client so that your client knows a certificate is needed in order to connect to the server.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html